# Rectangle.intersects not working properly

Tags: java, rectangles, intersect

I'm making a game that requires me to know where two objects collide. I decided to try and use Rectangles because I recently learned about the Rectangle.intersects() method. So I made a small 2 by 2 grid of rectangles that I mapped onto two players in the game like this

[Demonstration of rectangle grid on players](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVLcS.png)

The check for two rectangles intersecting is on a timer in a different class, the rectangles were made in the class for the players.

Creation of rectangles

```
    Rectangle playerHitBoxTL = new Rectangle(0, 0, 60 , 60);
    Rectangle playerHitBoxTR = new Rectangle(60, 0, 59, 60);
    Rectangle playerHitBoxBL = new Rectangle(0, 60, 60, 59);
    Rectangle playerHitBoxBR = new Rectangle(60, 60, 59, 59);
```

Adding them into the other class and checking if they collide

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Rectangle playerTL = thePlayer.playerHitBoxTL;
        Rectangle playerTR = thePlayer.playerHitBoxTR;
        Rectangle playerBL = thePlayer.playerHitBoxBL;
        Rectangle playerBR = thePlayer.playerHitBoxBR;
        Rectangle player2TL = testPlayer.playerHitBoxTL;
        Rectangle player2TR = testPlayer.playerHitBoxTR;
        Rectangle player2BL = testPlayer.playerHitBoxBL;
        Rectangle player2BR = testPlayer.playerHitBoxBR;
        if (playerBR.intersects(player2TL)){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"");
        }
    }
```

Obviously the end goal to see a JOptionPane appear if the bottom right rectangle of player 1 intersects with the top left rectangle of player two [however that never happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1eKU.png)

The timer has been started in the class holding the players. Was hoping you guys might have any suggestions?

EDIT:
It has been suggested that I place the code for movement as well

```
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        int code = arg0.getKeyCode(); //gets the int value of the key that was pressed
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_W) { //If the "w" key is pressed, move everything up
            thePlayer.setLocation(thePlayer.getLocation().x, thePlayer.getLocation().y - 5);
            bullet1.setLocation(bullet1.getLocation().x, bullet1.getLocation().y - 5);        
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A) { //if the "a" key is pressed, move everything down
            thePlayer.setLocation(thePlayer.getLocation().x - 5, thePlayer.getLocation().y);
            bullet1.setLocation(bullet1.getLocation().x - 5, bullet1.getLocation().y);
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S) { //if the "s" key is pressed move everything to the left
            thePlayer.setLocation(thePlayer.getLocation().x, thePlayer.getLocation().y + 5);
            bullet1.setLocation(bullet1.getLocation().x, bullet1.getLocation().y + 5);
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D) { //if the "d" key is pressed move everything to the right
            thePlayer.setLocation(thePlayer.getLocation().x + 5, thePlayer.getLocation().y);
            bullet1.setLocation(bullet1.getLocation().x + 5, bullet1.getLocation().y);
        }
}
```

EDIT 2: Figured out what the issue was, originally the rectangles were mapped onto the jpanels holding the characters not the frame holding the whole game. Made new rectangles in the frame class, set their proper location and dimensions to the characters and had them move around with the key listeners, the intersects method started to work the way I wanted it after that

Comment: What is the area of the two `Rectangle`'s intersection?  (The single point (60, 60)).  The javadoc for `Rectangle`'s `intersects` method says "Two rectangles intersect if their intersection is nonempty."  Apparently they've taken this to mean 'has a non-zero area' rather than 'contains any points'.

Comment: Additionally, why do you have a (I'm guessing) bottom/top left/right `Rectangle` for each player?  Should they not just have a _single_ `Rectangle` which goes from the bottom left to top right?

Comment: @user2478398 I'm a little confused by your first question. the first two coordinates represent in the top left corner of each rectangle in the player so they're slightly changed depending on where they are placed. the width and height of the rectangles are simply half the width and height of the player. Also, my end goal is for the player to be thrown back in one of four directions depending on which rectangle has been intersected with, thus the four rectangles.

Comment: I understand that.  Your code does 'BR intersects TL' (effectively).  Denoting rectangles as (Bottom Left) -> (Top Right).  You have BR = (60, 60) -> (119, 119).  TL = (0, 0) -> (60, 60).  These two rectangles only intersect at the one point (60, 60).  Hence the _area_ of their intersection is 0 (a single point has no area).  Thus the `Rectangle` class determines that they do _not_ intersect.  I.e. they 'touch', they do not intersect.

Comment: Oh, never mind, you didn't share code for moving (or mention it) so I assumed they hadn't moved from your construction here...  People will need more information to offer aid here, since `Rectangle.intersects` definitely does work...

Comment: I just placed the code for movement in